# How to test the negative actions on a test? Like when a call to the API fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, jestjs

I am attempting to test my actions when they fail. The actions that calls the API.

I have this:

```
export const loadTips = (tips: TipsModel): LoadTips => ({ tips, type: LOAD_TIPS });

export const fetchTips: ActionCreator<ThunkType> = () => async (dispatch) => {
  return ApiService.getTips(
    tips => dispatch(loadTips(tips)),
    () => dispatch(triggerToast('Tips are not loading. Try again later!', true))
  );
};
```

And these are the tests I have so far which are passing properly:

```
import * as actions from './tipsActions';
import { LOAD_TIPS, LoadTips, CLEAR_TIPS, ClearTips, DisableOrSnoozedTips, DISABLE_SNOOZ_TIP } from '../types/tipsTypes';
import getStore from '../services/mockGlobalStore';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import ApiService from '../services/apiService';

jest.mock('../services/apiService');
const mockedApiService = mocked(ApiService, true);

describe('tips actions on API', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockedApiService.mockClear();
  });

  const store = getStore();

  it('fetchTips makes API call', () => {
    store.dispatch(actions.fetchTips());

    expect(mockedApiService.getTips).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function), expect.any(Function));
  });
});

describe('tips actions', () => {
  it('creates a loadTips action', () => {
    const expectedAction: LoadTips = { type: LOAD_TIPS, tips: dummyTips };

    expect(actions.loadTips(dummyTips)).toEqual(expectedAction);
  });
});
```

So I want to know what can I do to test for example when the action fails it will dispatch the action:

```
dispatch(triggerToast('Tips are not loading. Try again later!', true))
```

So how can I test that part?

Answer (score 2):

In your case it would be the same as positive testing: you need to mock `ApiService.getTips` so it would call either "positive feedback" or "negative feedback". Say, by now  you don't test that `fetchTips` action is dispatched when `getTips` is succeeded.

It would be something alike(without typescript):

```
it('dispatches loadTips on success', () => {
  const mockedResponse = [1,2,3];
  ApiService.getTips.mockImplementation(
    (successCallback, failureCallback) => successCallback(mockedResponse)
  );
  store.dispatch(actions.fetchTips());
  expect(store.getActions()).toContainEqual(actions.loadTips(mockedResponse));
  expect(store.getActions()).not.toContainEqual(
    triggerToast('Tips are not loading. Try again later!', true)
  );
});

it('dispatches toast message on failure', () => {
  ApiService.getTips.mockImplementation(
    (successCallback, failureCallback) => failureCallback()
  );
  store.dispatch(actions.fetchTips());
  expect(store.getActions()).toContainEqual(
    triggerToast('Tips are not loading. Try again later!', true)
  );
  expect(store.getActions()).not.toContainEqual(actions.loadTips(mockedResponse));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is negetive test u have to call api with negative data. Check the implementation of ApiService.getTips and throw error. Or Mock ApiService.getTips and throw error(**call error callback**)

```
ApiService.getTips(
    tips => dispatch(loadTips(tips)),
    () => dispatch(triggerToast('Tips are not loading. Try again later!', true))
  )
```